# How to install Maven into Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6?

Tags: linux, maven, redhat, yum

I'm working on a Scientific Linux box and am trying to install Maven using the `yum` command. Scientific Linux for those of you who do not know is based off of Red Hat Linux Enterprise Edition 6.

I'd prefer to install Maven in a way that lent itself to easy updating, that is why I have shied away from simply going to the Apache Maven site and getting the files I need.
Simply running `yum` with root privileges was not enough. I used `yum search maven` which returned "JPackage Utilities", which I tried to install only to get:

```
Package jpackage-utils-1.7.5-3.12.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
```

I was assuming that something like creating a new repo file something like `/etc/yum.repos.d/maven.repo` would do the trick.
I found a site suggesting that I point my maven.repo file to the URL http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo, however this seems to be a fix for an older version of Linux as it did not solve my problem

As always thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: This is very useful for those unaware that you must install "maven" even though *"mvn"* is the actual executable's name. Further, it seemed like maven2 and maven download different versions. All this is not choices we're used to in a world where each distro supports a single version with an "obvious" installer mirroring of the executable's name.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The distro agnostic generic repo is what you want. As root, add a couple of the jpackage-generic repos to yum (two snippets below). Then perform a yum update and finally yum install maven2.

```
cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage-generic-free.repo << EOF
[jpackage-generic-free]
name=JPackage generic free
baseurl=http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/6.0/generic/free/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
EOF

cat > /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage-generic-devel.repo << EOF
[jpackage-generic-devel]
name=JPackage Generic Developer
baseurl=http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/jpackage/6.0/generic/devel/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage.asc
EOF
```

Comment: Tried this, and got a series of dependency issues, pasted here: 
http://pastebin.com/A6uguJuG. Are the repos out of date?

Comment: I tried this as well and get the following dependency issue: http://codepad.org/4AdW0NwF

Answer (score 9):

I had all kinds of conflicts trying to use the JPackage repo with Scientific Linux 6.2, but I had much better luck with [dchen's repo](http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/) from the "Fedora People" unofficial repositories. The repo config I used is:

```
# Note: Replaced $releasever with 6Server since SL's "6.2" doesn't work

[epel-apache-maven]
name=maven from apache foundation.
baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6Server/$basearch/
enabled=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
gpgcheck=0

[epel-apache-maven-source]
name=maven from apache foundation. - Source
baseurl=http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6Server/SRPMS
enabled=0
skip_if_unavailable=1
gpgcheck=0
```

The package itself is called `apache-maven` and installs maven 3.0.3.

Comment: This works well, but for some reason installs maven into /usr/share/apache-maven/bin.  I would have expected the binaries to end up in my $PATH.

Comment: who is `dchen`, and is that repo secure and under maintenance?

Comment: @vbem Chen is a [RedHat engineer](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User:Dchen), and the repo was [last updated](https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/dchen/apache-maven/epel-6Server/SRPMS/) in May 2016. I don't personally know how to assess the security of the repository, but you can read the fedorapeople.org [user guidance](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/fedorapeople.org) and make your own judgment.

Answer (score 5):

This is more updated way:

```
curl http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo > /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage.repo
yum update
yum install maven2
```

Comment: This give maven 2.0.7 which is woefully out of date.

Comment: `yum install maven` installs latest maven version. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Andy for his answer (on Jun 10, 2011).  It gave me some hints.  However, when I followed it, I got a lot of dependencies issues, including problems like these

```
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by plexus-container-default-1.0-0.a9s1.2.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by aspectj-1.5.4-1.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by rhino-1.7-1.r2.8.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by saxon9-dom-B.9.0.0.8-2.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by easymock2-2.5.2-2.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by saxon9-B.9.0.0.8-2.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by saxon9-xpath-B.9.0.0.8-2.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by xmlbeans-2.4.0-3.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by jtidy-7.0-0.V04aug2000r7_dev.2.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by lucene-2.4.1-5.jpp6.noarch
rpmlib(FileDigests) is needed by aqute-bndlib-0.0.363-1.jpp6.noarch
```

Finally I realized the JPackage website actually has good and updated instruction.  So I following these two pages and could finally installed maven2 on my machine.

Jpackage.org: [Installation](http://www.jpackage.org/installation.php)

Jpackage.org: [Using a Repository -- Yum](http://www.jpackage.org/yum.php)