# Installing Maven 3.0.5 in RedHat Linux

Tags: linux, maven, wget, tar, yum

Can anyone help me installing maven 3.0.5 in linux please?

I tried using `wget`, `yum` and `tar` command. All the commands are saying its not recognized as an external or internal command and now I am blank as to how to achieve it. Do we need to go to `start->cmd` and apply these commands??

And also please tell me how to set the environment variable. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the enviroment variable MAVEN_HOME ?

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076326/how-to-install-maven2-on-redhat-linux

Comment: It's hard to figure much from the question, but it appears that you have messed up with the `PATH` environment variable (especially if `tar` cannot be recognised as a command).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The first thing we need to do is to download the Maven tar file and untar it to a shared location on the workstation

```
wget http://mirrors.gigenet.com/apache/maven/maven-3/3.0.5/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz
su -c "tar -zxvf apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/"
```

Setup the Maven Environment Variables in shared profile.
The next step is to setup the Maven environment variables in a shared profile so all users on the system will get them import at login time.

```
su -c "vi /etc/profile.d/maven.sh"

# Add the following lines to maven.sh
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Now test your install of Maven.
Logout of the system and then log back into it. Enter the following command:

```
[jsmith@regan ~]$ mvn -version
```

If you did everything right your output should look something like the one below:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 08:51:28-0500)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_19, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.19/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.i686", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting the following error if i check the installation using "mvn -version",

Comment: -bash: /opt/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin/mvn: Permission denied.What will be the problem? please help me

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chetan. I would like to add that the JAVA_HOME environment variable should be set correctly as well.

Comment: That seems standard solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The above link will not work,it was corrupted, If you want latest versions please find the below link:
`wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz`

**Steps:**

1. Download the file at `/opt/Maven/apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz`
2. Extract the file in same location `tar xvf apache-maven-3.0.5-bin.tar.gz` and Run.
3. Open `vi /etc/profile`
4. Paste these line:

   > export M2_HOME=/opt/Maven/apache-maven-3.0.5
   >
   > export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
5. Save the file.
6. Run `source /etc/profile`
7. Finally Run `mvn -version` and you will get the maven version

Maven installation done.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $JAVA_HOME if returns empty(export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home)
echo $PATH if returns empty(export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin)
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.3
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
mvn --version
ALL SET *******

In case if this doesn't work after this step,

vi .profile
export PATH={$PATH}:'/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.3/bin/
```