# MAVEN_HOME, MVN_HOME or M2_HOME

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

What's the correct Maven environment variable name: `MAVEN_HOME`, `MVN_HOME` or `M2_HOME`?

I've found some details about `MAVEN_HOME` and `M2_HOME` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136324/what-is-the-difference-between-m2-home-and-maven-home). But I also have seen `MVN_HOME` around.

Comment: It's depends. Please extract your zip or tar file and then  find the env variable inside `bin/mvn` or `bin/mvn.cmd`. Maven home variable name depends on which  `M2_HOME|MVN_HOME|MAVEN_HOME` used by it's distribution. During the time of comments I found the most recent version of maven **3.8.4** which one usages `MAVEN_HOME` instead of `M2_HOME` !

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I've personally never found it useful to set `M2_HOME`.

What counts is your $PATH environment. Hijacking part of the answer from Danix, all you need is:

```
export PATH=/Users/xxx/sdk/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:$PATH
```

The `mvn` script computes `M2_HOME` for you anyway for what it's worth.

Comment: +1. I'd even say setting `M2_HOME` in the past has always lead to weird errors, mostly `NoClassDefFoundError` because the `mvn` command would be found in the PATH, but with another Maven version found through `M2_HOME`. My life has been better since I've stopped setting that env var and only rely on adding `.../bin/mvn`'s directory to `PATH` and let Maven autodetect things.

Comment: "I've personally never found it useful to set M2_HOME." And you was right. That is deprecated : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47712646/270371

Answer (score 63):

`M2_HOME` (and the like) is not to be used as of Maven 3.5.0. See [MNG-5607](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5607) and [Release Notes](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html) for details.

Answer (score 28):

Here is my Maven setup. You can use it as an example. You don't need anything else in order to use Maven.

M2_HOME is used for both Maven 2 and 3

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/xxx/sdk/apache-maven-3.0.5
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1048m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=312M"
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

Answer (score 10):

**MAVEN_HOME is used for maven 1** and **M2_HOME** **is used to locate maven 2**.  Having the two different _HOME variables means it is possible to run both on the same machine.
And if you check old **mvn.cmd** scripts they have something like,

```
@REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Maven2 Start Up Batch script
@REM
@REM Required ENV vars:
@REM JAVA_HOME - location of a JDK home dir
@REM
@REM Optional ENV vars
@REM M2_HOME - location of maven2's installed home dir
@REM MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO - set to 'on' to enable the echoing of the batch commands
@REM MAVEN_BATCH_PAUSE - set to 'on' to wait for a key stroke before ending
@REM MAVEN_OPTS - parameters passed to the Java VM when running Maven
@REM     e.g. to debug Maven itself, use
@REM set MAVEN_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
@REM MAVEN_SKIP_RC - flag to disable loading of mavenrc files
@REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

See that `@REM M2_HOME - location of maven2's installed home dir`

Anyway usage of this pattern is now deprecated with maven 3.5 as per the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html).

> Based on problems in using M2_HOME related to different Maven versions installed and to simplify things, the usage of M2_HOME has been removed and is not supported any more [MNG-5823](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5823), [MNG-5836](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5836), [MNG-5607](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5607)

So now the mvn.cmd look like,

```
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
@REM Apache Maven Startup Script
@REM
@REM Environment Variable Prerequisites
@REM
@REM   JAVA_HOME          Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
@REM   MAVEN_BATCH_ECHO  (Optional) Set to 'on' to enable the echoing of the batch commands.
@REM   MAVEN_BATCH_PAUSE (Optional) set to 'on' to wait for a key stroke before ending.
@REM   MAVEN_OPTS        (Optional) Java runtime options used when Maven is executed.
@REM   MAVEN_SKIP_RC     (Optional) Flag to disable loading of mavenrc files.
@REM -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So what you need is JAVA_HOME to be set correctly. As per the [new installation guide (as of 12/29/2017)](https://maven.apache.org/install.html),
Just add the maven bin directory path to the PATH variable. It should do the trick.

ex : `export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, the current way to locate `settings.xml` is to go to `%USERPROFILE%`. There, a directory `.m2` is contained, where one finds `settings.xml`.

**Never use `M2_HOME`. It is unsupported since Apache Maven 3.5.0:**

> Based on problems in using `M2_HOME` related to different Maven versions installed and to simplify things, the usage of `M2_HOME` has been removed and is not supported any more [MNG-5823](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5823), [MNG-5836](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5836), [MNG-5607](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5607).
>
> Important change for windows users: The usage of `%HOME%` has been replaced with `%USERPROFILE%` [MNG-6001](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6001)
>
> Source: https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html#overview-about-the-changes

Note: I stumbled over the question as [chocolatey](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chocolatey/info)'s Apache Maven package sets `M2_HOME` - and I wanted to locate `settings.xml`.

Answer (score -1):

`$M2_HOME`is used sometimes, for example, to install [`Takari Extensions for Apache Maven`](http://takari.io/book/30-team-maven.html)

One way to find `$M2_HOME` value is to search for `mvn`:

```
sudo find / -name "mvn" 2>/dev/null
```

And, probably it will be: `/opt/maven/`

Comment: I do not see anything on the linked page suggesting that `M2_HOME` is read by something in Takari. It is just using a placeholder variable in examples of shell commands you could run.

Answer (score -2):

I have solved same issue with following:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/share/maven
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -8):

We have M2_HOME,MAVEN_HOME,M3_HOME all are available in market
Previously M2_HOME is the only environment variable used by all as a standard.
But,due latest releases the MAVEN_Home came as standard but some old tools are still trying to find only M2_HOME
so we should have both M2_HOME,MAVEN_HOME to sustain with old and new tools.
M2_HOME can be used for both as well