# Raspberry Pi check $M2_HOME environmental variable and mvn script match

Tags: maven, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Whenever I use maven in my raspberry pi (if I run commands such as, `mvn exec:exec` or `mvn --version` in my terminal), I get the following error:

`Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.`

I checked my $M2_HOME environmental variable by running `echo $M2_HOME` in the terminal, and the following is the value:
`/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9`

So how do I check if it's matched with the mvn script in my raspberry pi (NOOBS)?

===============================================================

**Found a Solution, See Below:**

To fix this issue I re-installed maven in my raspberry pi using the Linux instructions from the following tutorial:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm

1) Find out where Maven is installed, use the command `echo $M2_HOME` or the command `whereis mvn`

- maven is installed in the following path in my raspberry pi:
   /opt/apache-maven-3.3.9

2) In the terminal enter the following commands to set the environmental variable M2, it'll be the bin folder in the maven installation folder

`export M2=$M2_HOME/bin`

3) Append M2 to the Path environmental variable

`export PATH=$M2:$PATH`

4) Now check to see if maven works by running the following command in terminal:

`mvn -version`

For some reason my changes aren't sticking, so if you close out of your Raspberry Pi you might have to re-do these steps.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609922/maven-home-mvn-home-or-m2-home/26610326#26610326

Comment: Thank you for answering this Steve. I was hoping to find a way to match my mvn script, which I don't where to find, and possibly make adjustments to get them to match.

Comment: Simply omit M2_HOME only add the bin folder of the maven distro to the PATH nothing more is needed. so in the end `export PATH:opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH`..