# maven work without environment variable in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu

I'm currently working on an ubuntu pc.I created maven project in eclipse and Build it by giving the goals "clean install". it created war files.

But when I search maven home environment variable using commands `printenv`
it shows nothing like M2_HOME in the output list.

when I give the command `echo $M2_HOME` it shows blank line.

when I give the command  `mvn --version` it gives me the flowing output

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation 
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-109-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

my question is, can maven work without environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can maven work without environment variable?

Yes - and you just proved it.  :-)  By default, with your distribution, `/usr/share/maven` is your `$M2_HOME`*.

If you navigate to a directory containing a `pom.xml` and run `mvn clean install`, you should also get a successful build.

2 additional notes:

First, Eclipse (at least Eclipse for Java EE Developers) includes its own embedded Maven installation by default - so you don't necessarily even need Maven to be installed at the OS level.  If you have both, depending upon how things are configured, you may end up using the same or separate copies of local repositories, etc.

Second, and to expand upon the above * - at least as of Maven 3.5.0, `M2_HOME` is no more.  As per https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html :

> Based on problems in using M2_HOME related to different Maven versions installed and to simplify things, the usage of M2_HOME has been removed and is not supported any more MNG-5823, MNG-5836, MNG-5607.

See also:

- [MAVEN_HOME, MVN_HOME or M2_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609922/maven-home-mvn-home-or-m2-home)

To summarize the above reference, what really matters is your `PATH` variable - not `M2_HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

All Maven needs to work is the path to Java in your `PATH` environment variable. This is the minimum requirement. It is able to derive all the other HOME variables for its own use. On top of this, if you want to be able to run maven from any directory (rather than `chdir`ing every time into maven's bin folder), you can add Maven's own bin folder also to `PATH`.

Note: The M2_HOME variable is actually [being removed](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html) in maven 3.5.0. So it should not be used anymore.