# Maven Invoker - Using MVNW

Tags: java, maven-invoker-plugin

I use maven invoker to compile generated source code programmatically.
I work now inside container and I would like to avoid of embedding `MAVEN` as well.
Currently the code (that runs locally) generally looks like this (I simplified it a bit):

```java
InvocationRequest request = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
request.setPomFile(new File("pom.xml"));
 
request.setGoals(Collections.singletonList("test"));
Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
invoker.setMavenHome(new File(System.getenv("M2_HOME")));
try {
    invoker.execute(request);
} catch (MavenInvocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to redirect the invoker to the `MVNW` (Maven wrapper) I have along with the code.
Anyone has an idea if this is possible or supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's possible

Although the creators of the plugin seem not to support that aspect directly, you can configure the Maven Invoker API to run Maven Wrapper using the Invoker's methods `setMavenExecutable` and `setMavenHome`.
There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Using an **absolute path** of the Maven Wrapper script

   ```
   Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
   invoker.setMavenHome(Path.of(".").toFile());

   invoker.setMavenExecutable(new File("/home/user/projects/sample/mvnw"));
   ```
2. Using a **relative path** of the Maven Wrapper script

   ```
   Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
   invoker.setMavenHome(Path.of(".").toFile());

   invoker.setMavenExecutable(new File("../mvnw"));
   ```

You can set the executable without any problem if MVNW script's path is absolute.

When it's relative then the internals of the plugin will try to prepend the `<M2_HOME>/bin/` path - you have to skip (`../`) one parent folder when declaring the executable location (so the final path seen by the plugin will look like `<M2_HOME>/bin/../mvnw`).

As for `M2_HOME` - you have to set it via the API as well because of the plugin requirements. If you won't configure it, an exception will be raised:

> Maven application directory was not specified, and ${maven.home} is
> not provided in the system properties. Please specify at least on of
> these.

Thankfully, you can safely set it to your project directory because [since Maven 3.5.0 `M2_HOME` env is not necessary anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47712646/14355061).

If your MVNW script is not placed in the main directory of the project, you have to configure the paths appropriately.

While writing this answer I was using `maven-invoker:3.0.1`.