# How to install Maven in Putty.exe?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, maven, putty

I have to build and compile my project through Putty(through a remote linux environment). I am unable to execute maven commands(such as mvn compile, mvn test etc) in Putty as it cannot identify "mvn" as a command. For this I need to install maven in my remote system. How do I do it?

Comment: I have an extracted file of maven in my remote. I am trying to add the environment variables using these commands: export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1 export M2=$M2_HOME/bin export PATH=$M2:$PATH  It says permission denied when I check maven using mvn -version. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Is putty used to connect via ssh to the remote computer? If you are logged in type the following command in the terminal:

curl http://apache.panu.it/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz > maven.tar.gz

Then follow instruction on site to install it: [LINK](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

You can also use sudo `apt-get install maven` but I don't know which version is on repository.

Comment: yes via ssh. this command results incurl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'apache.panu.it'

Comment: I did the command in m terminal and it works well. My mirror is in Italy, find out the file on the correct/preferred mirror [HERE](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

Comment: I am able to download the file but not through putty.

Comment: I'm not getting you... If you are connected with ssh to the remote computer, and you have root/sudo access, you can download the file directly to the remote computer and then install it there.

Comment: probably you need sudo before. I mean `sudo curl http://apache.panu.it/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.tar.gz > maven.tar.gz` or `sudo apt-get install maven`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install maven`

That is, if you have Ubuntu.

[How to install maven2 on redhat linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076326/how-to-install-maven2-on-redhat-linux)

there is a thread for maven on red hat.

Comment: what Linux distribution do you have installed on your remote?

Comment: you need to include such information in your question.

Comment: I have an extracted file of maven in my remote. I am trying to add the environment variables using these commands: export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1

export M2=$M2_HOME/bin

export PATH=$M2:$PATH