# mvn command not found

Tags: maven, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit, magic-mirror

So I am extremely new to Raspberry Pi and this is my first project. I am trying to build a smart mirror that includes Amazon Alexa, I'm following a tutorial and have made it most of the way but I get stuck at step 7 (https://github.com/alexa/alexa-avs-sample-app/wiki/Raspberry-Pi#lets-get-started), when I enter the command

cd javaclient && mvn exec:exec

I get: bash: mvn: command not found

I have searched and searched and I cannot find a solution to why it will not work. I have a theory that it may have something to do with Maven maybe, at least thats what my google results bring up. Any help here guys?

PS: I followed MichMich's magic mirror tutorial for the actual magic mirror part that is working perfectly https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror#installation

EDIT:
So I followed what vikiiii posted and made it to the part where I set the environmental variables. How and where do I set those? The more I google the more confused I get.

[How to install maven2 on redhat linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076326/how-to-install-maven2-on-redhat-linux?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

EDIT:
I got it working!! Thanks so much Afgan, your walkthrough got me through it!

Comment: Install maven https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076326/how-to-install-maven2-on-redhat-linux?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @vikiiii I followed all the steps with the most updated version and when I go to verify, I still get "bash: mvn: command not found"

Comment: Make sure maven is added to your path.

Comment: @tcansler follow this  link [Install Apache Maven on Linux](http://www.javahelps.com/2017/10/install-apache-maven-on-linux.html)